# What does asterisk "*" mean in a unix PATH environment variable?

Tags: unix, environment-variables, path, wildcards

Example:

```
# echo $PATH
/home/admin*:*/bin
```

I assume it's a wildcard of some sort, but is it one level deep, or many?

For example, will `*/bin` match only items in `usr/bin` or will it also match deeper items in `usr/local/bin` `and /home/admin/bin`? And will `/home/admin*` match `/home/administrator` and everything under it, also at multiple levels?

Comment: If this belongs in the Unix & Linux StackExchange site, please let me know how I can migrate it over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What does asterisk (*) mean in a unix $PATH?

```
# echo $PATH
/home/admin*:*/bin
```

It means you have an invalid `$PATH`.

`$PATH` does not support wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

This [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1010309/354504) states your `$PATH` is invalid, but I disagree.

That's because, in `bash` at least, it won't cause any errors - either when you set it, or when the shell tries to resolve a command via $PATH.

In $PATH, an asterisk means a *literal* `*` (asterisk).

That is, there is **NO** wildcard expansion performed, and it is actually checking the literal directory `/home/admin*`, which doesn't exist so it skips it, and it checks `*/bin`, which is also similarly ignored.

---

You *can* create directories with a literal `*` in them (but... but... *why*?).
And, if done, then it *will* look there; eg, in the `'*/bin'` path

So, this would actually work with your given $PATH value:

```
cd /
mkdir \*
mkdir \*/bin
echo 'echo Hello from \"star\"/bin' > \*/bin/asterisk.bash
chmod 744 \*/bin/asterisk.bash

asterisk.bash
```

(If you want to try it out in a local directory instead of root, just don't `cd` into `/`)
(*Not* that I recommend doing this at home.  Do it at a friend's house :-)

But since you probably did it anyway -- well, to get rid of the ridiculousness, the following three commands should do it.
(NB: I am **not** using `rm -r` just in case something gets mistyped or the shell you're in interprets things differently.)

```
rm \*/bin/asterisk.sh
rmdir \*/bin
rmdir \*
```